In the category defined by $\le$ on $\mathbb{Z}$, every morphism defined is a monomorphism and an epimorphism
I am studying with Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0", and got stuck on proving the statement on pg. 30 here:

... in Set, a function is an isomorphism if and only if it is both
injective and surjective, hence if and only if it is both a
monomorphism and an epimorphism. But in the category defined by $\le$
on $\mathbb{Z}$, every morphism is both a monomorphism and an
epimorphism, while the only isomorphisms are the identities (Example
4.5).

where the category defined is


obejcts: the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$;
morphisms: if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then let ${\rm Hom}(a,b)$ be the set consisting of the element $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$
if $a \le b$ and let ${\rm Hom}(a,b) = \emptyset$ o/w;
$1_a = (a,a) \in {\rm Hom}(a,a)$;
composition: for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $$f \in {\rm Hom}(a,b), \quad g \in {\rm Hom}(b,c),$$ $$gf:= (a,c) \in {\rm Hom}(a,c).$$


Then, to prove every morphism is monomorphism, I tried the following:

Let $f \in {\rm Hom}(a,b)$ and $g,h \in {\rm Hom}(x,a)$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $fg = fh$. That is, ...

But I was not sure how to proceed from here, because I am thinking $g,h \in {\rm Hom}(x,a)$ already implies $g=h=(x,a)$. Similarly to prove every morphism is epimorphism, it is obvious from the supposition.
So, I have two questions:

If what I wrote in the last paragraph is right, how do I complete the proof more clearly?
Am I missing something?


Do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. See here.

@ArturoMagidin I see! Thanks for letting me know!

If $fh=fg$, then there exist an object $x$ such that $g,h\in \mathrm{Hom}(x,a)$. Since $\mathrm{Hom}(x,a)=\{(x,a)\}$, then $g=h=(x,a)$. Thus, $g=h$ so $f$ is a monomorphism.
A symmetric argument shows $f$ is an epimorphism.
No, you aren't missing anything. Since Hom sets have at most one element, every arrow is both an epimorphism and a monomorphism. (However, only the identity arrows are isomorphisms in this category).

Thank you so much for your answer! Helped a lot for my understanding!
